# Port 22 blocked on AWS instance, can't SSH

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, ufw

I enabled UFW on my ec2 instance and followed the following steps:

```
abhi@my-ip-address:~$ sudo ufw default deny incoming
abhi@my-ip-address:~$ sudo ufw allow 2200/tcp
abhi@my-ip-address:~$ sudo ufw allow 80/tcp
abhi@my-ip-address:~$ sudo ufw allow 123/udp
```

I did this in a hurry, and forgot to open `port 22` on the server to enable SSH access. After doing some research, I found that I could another port number from my AWS console which I can then use to SSH into the server. So my **`Security Group`** tab looks something like this: [image]

---

Then I used the following command to ssh into the my ec2 instance from local machine:

> ssh -p 2200 -i photosite-app.pem ubuntu@my-ec2-ip

But get the following error message:

> ssh: connect to host xx.xx.xx.xx port 2200: Connection refused

---

I am a newbie, and I realized my mistake only after it was late! Is there anyway, I could use a different port to ssh into my EC2 instance ? Any help is appreciated!

Thank you :)

**EDIT:1**
Tried to ssh with port 80 too:

```
~/.ssh » ssh -p 80 -i photosite-app.pem ubuntu@xx.xx.xx.xx
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Comment: Have you reconfigured SSH to listen on port 2200? There is nothing stopping you from changing the port your ssh server(s) listen on, but that is something you need to configure ahead of time. Unless you omitted something in your question, it rather sounds like you might have locked yourself out of SSH access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those other ports will only work if your sshd is **listening** on those ports, which it's not unless you explicitly configured it to do so.

You'll need to either scrap this instance and start over, or mount this server' root fs to another instance where you can fix the firewall rules.

Answer (score 0):

After many days of struggling with this issue i found solution!!
You just have to stop your instances and de-attach your volumes and reattach them and it will work like charm.

Hope it help.